# Using a MTLTexture as the environment map of a SCNScene

Tags: swift, scenekit, metal, metalkit, mtlbuffer

I want to set a `MTLTexture` object as the environment map of a scene, as it seems to be possible according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterialproperty/1395372-contents#discussion). I can set the environment map to be a `UIImage` with the following code:

```
let roomImage = UIImage(named: "room")
scene.lightingEnvironment.contents = roomImage
```

This works and I see the reflection of the image on my metallic objects. I tried converting the image to a `MTLTexture` and setting it as the environment map with the following code:

```
let roomImage = UIImage(named: "room")
let loader = MTKTextureLoader(device: MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!)
let envMap = try? loader.newTexture(cgImage: (roomImage?.cgImage)!, options: nil)
scene.lightingEnvironment.contents = envMap
```

However this does not work and I end up with a blank environment map with no reflection on my objects.

Also, instead of setting the `options` as `nil`, I tried setting the `MTKTextureLoader.Option.textureUsage` key with [every possible value](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtltextureusage#1604533) it can get, but that didn't work either.

Edit: You can have a look at the example project in [this](https://github.com/svtek/ARKitEnvironmentMapper) repo and use it to reproduce this use case.

Comment: I believe this is a supported use case. What are the dimensions of your image? What format is it in (I assume PNG)? Does `envMap` contain a non-`nil` value after you finish loading? Can you QuickLook it (visually inspect its contents) in Xcode if you set a breakpoint right after the line where you load it?

Comment: @warrenm The image is a 1024x512 PNG file. `envMap` seems to be successfully created and Quick Look shows the same image as `roomImage`.

Comment: [Time to file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Published a working solution.

Comment: @AndyJazz It's been a long time since I abandoned this project and this platform, so I'll take your word for it and accept your answer since you seem to have put an incredibly detailed solution out there. Thank you for your efforts!

Comment: Hi @halileohalilei, It's never too late to answer a question with +31 upvotes. )))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Lighting SCN Environment with an MTK texture

Using Xcode 13.3.1 on macOS 12.3.1 for iOS 15.4 app.

The trick is, the environment lighting requires a cube texture, not a flat image.

- Create 6 square images for MetalKit cube texture

[image]

- in Xcode `Assets` folder create Cube Texture Set

[image]

- place textures to their corresponding slots

[image]

- mirror images horizontally and vertically, if needed

[image]

Paste the code:

```
import ARKit
import MetalKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()    
        let scene = SCNScene()
        
        let imageName = "CubeTextureSet"
        let textureLoader = MTKTextureLoader(device: sceneView.device!)

        let environmentMap = try! textureLoader.newTexture(name: imageName, 
                                                    scaleFactor: 2, 
                                                         bundle: .main, 
                                                        options: nil)
        
        let daeScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/testCube.dae")!

        let model = daeScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "polyCube", 
                                             recursively: true)!
        
        scene.lightingEnvironment.contents = environmentMap
        scene.lightingEnvironment.intensity = 2.5
        scene.background.contents = environmentMap

        sceneView.scene = scene
        sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(model)
    }
}
```

Apply metallic materials to models. Now MTL environment lighting is On.

[image]

If you need a procedural skybox texture – use [MDLSkyCubeTexture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71837509/scenekit-how-can-i-programmatically-adjust-sun-elevation-parameter/71837824#71837824) class.

Also, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71857942/scenekit-loading-lightingenvironment-and-bg-from-hdr-has-no-effect/71858221#71858221) may be useful for you.