# SceneKit – How can I programmatically adjust 'Sun elevation' parameter?

Tags: swift, swiftui, scenekit

I've managed to incorporate SceneKit into a SwiftUI view in my app using the following code:

```
import SwiftUI
import SceneKit

struct ContentView: View {
    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    let lightNode = SCNNode()
    let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
    @State var ship: SCNNode = SCNNode()
        
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            SceneView(
                scene: scene,
                pointOfView: cameraNode,
                options: [.autoenablesDefaultLighting, .allowsCameraControl ]
            )                
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .padding()    
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .onAppear {
            cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
            scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
            cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 15)

            lightNode.light = SCNLight()
            lightNode.light!.type = .omni
            lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 10)
            scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)
            ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
            ambientLightNode.light!.type = .ambient
            ambientLightNode.light!.color = UIColor.darkGray
             
            scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)
            
            ship = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "ship", 
                                         recursively: true)!
            ship.runAction(SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0,
                                                                      y: 0.1,
                                                                      z: 0,
                                                               duration: 1)))
        }            
    }
}
```

I know that you can use scene.fogEndDistance and other permutations to programmatically adjust the fog using Swift. I was playing around with scene.background but can't find any method exposed that allows me to change the sun's elevation.

How do I use Swift to programmatically change the sun's elevation for my SceneKit scene?

Comment: Try to use a @State var for lightNode position . Then upon some event, change the position values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simultaneously use MDL Sky Box for scene lighting and for BG:

```
sceneView.scene?.background.contents = MDLSkyCubeTexture(name: "procedural sky",
                                              channelEncoding: .float32,
                                            textureDimensions: vector_int2(512,512),
                                                    turbidity: 0.12,
                                                 sunElevation: 1.00,
                                    upperAtmosphereScattering: 0.05,
                                                 groundAlbedo: 0.32)

sceneView.scene?.lightingEnvironment.contents = sceneView.scene?.background.contents

sceneView.scene?.lightingEnvironment.intensity = 2.0
```

Comment: Andy, thank you. That did the trick. I was looking for a way to expose the procedural sky and your code worked. Thanks for the "swift" answer.