# How to make SceneView's background clear in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, scenekit

I am showing a 3D object in SwiftUI, and I have a problem with making the object's background clear. I have searched and did not find any solution. Is there any solution for this?

```
private var scene: SCNScene? {
    SCNScene(named: "Globe.scnassets/sphere.scn")
}
    
private var cameraNode: SCNNode? {
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 5)
    return cameraNode
}

var body: some View {
    SceneView(scene: scene,
        pointOfView: cameraNode,
            options: [.allowsCameraControl, .autoenablesDefaultLighting])
}
```

Comment: Did you try this? sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

Comment: @ZAY My question is about SwiftUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are, at least, 3 ways to programmatically change a BG in SwiftUI's SceneView.

### Default white background

[image]

### Changing SCNScene's background color

[image]

```
import SwiftUI
import SceneKit

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var scene = SCNScene(named: "model.usdz")
    var options: SceneView.Options = [.autoenablesDefaultLighting,
                                      .allowsCameraControl ]

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            SceneView(scene: scene, options: options)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            let _ = scene?.background.contents = UIColor.black
        }
    }
}
```

### Using textured double-sided SCNGeometry

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var scene = SCNScene(named: "model.usdz")
    var options: SceneView.Options = [.autoenablesDefaultLighting,
                                      .allowsCameraControl ]
    let node = SCNNode(geometry: SCNSphere(radius: 500.0))
    let img = UIImage(named: "image.jpg")

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            let _ = node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = img
            let _ = node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
            let _ = scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(node)

            SceneView(scene: scene, options: options)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
    }
}
```

### Using Procedural Sky Box Texture

You can use [MDLSkyCubeTexture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71837509/scenekit-how-can-i-programmatically-adjust-sun-elevation-parameter/71837824#71837824) as `background` and `lightingEnvironment`.

Comment: Thank you for the great answers but unfortunately, it doesn't work with light/dark mode. If I change the appearance it won't affect the background.

Comment: Post your code here in comments, please.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution via SceneKit editor, if you want to show an image as background, you can manually do it by going to:

```
Scene Inspector -> Background and lighting -> Background
```

and set the image as background:
[image]