# SceneKit – Loading HDR or EXR lightingEnvironment has no effect

Tags: swift, swiftui, scenekit, skybox

I tried loading an `.hdr` file to use it as a skybox and use its lighting informations. This is the code I used:

```
backgroundColor = UIColor.gray 
// check if a default skybox is added

let environment = UIImage(named: "studio_small_09_2k.hdr")
scene?.lightingEnvironment.contents = environment
scene?.lightingEnvironment.intensity = 1.0
scene?.background.contents = environment
```

Unfortunately I recieve a grey screen and also no errors. Has anyone experience in using hdr files in SceneKit?

XCode Version: 13.2.1
iOS version: 15.3.1
hdr file: https://polyhaven.com/a/studio_small_09

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use a [Cube Texture Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47739214/using-a-mtltexture-as-the-environment-map-of-a-scnscene/52202973#52202973), where each of 6 images is square `(height == width)`.

Also, the following cube map representations are supported:

- Vertical strip as single image `(height == 6 * width)`
- Horizontal strip as single image `(6 * height == width)`
- Spherical projection as single image `(2 * height == width)`

Here's a SwiftUI code:

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SCNView {

    let sceneView = SCNView(frame: .zero)
    sceneView.scene = SCNScene()
    // if EXR or HDR is 2:1 spherical map, it really meets the requirements
    sceneView.scene?.lightingEnvironment.contents = UIImage(named: "std.exr")
    sceneView.backgroundColor = .black
    sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
    sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
    
    let node = SCNNode()
    node.geometry = SCNSphere(radius: 0.1)
    node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.lightingModel = .physicallyBased
    node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.metalness.contents = 1.0
    sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
    return sceneView
}
```

Pay particular attention – you need `.physicallyBased` lighting model to get HDR or EXR reflections.

[image]

And let's set it for BG:

```
sceneView.scene?.background.contents = UIImage(named: "std.exr")
```

[image]

**Why your `.exr` doesn't work?**

The solutions is simple: delete your `.exr` from project, empty the Trash and after that drag-and-drop `.exr` file, in `Choose options for adding these files` window choose `Add to targets`:

[image]

Now your `.exr` must work.

Comment: Thanks! I'll go for a cube texture set then and don't use the asset in my example. So the hdr format simply is not going to work in this context? But I was kind of irritated because the image I was using looks quite a lot like a spherical projection and has 2048 × 1024 pixels. Shouldn't it work already then?

Comment: Both `.hdr` and `.exr` images work in SceneKit.

Comment: Thanks for your update. After setting `autoenablesDefaultLighting = true` the ambient light information from hdr works perfectly fine. But still I don't get the desired result for `scene?.background.contents = UIImage(named: "std.hdr")`.

Comment: No I’m still sticking to my example and have the UIImage stored in a variable. So no copy/paste/name errors. Maybe it’s because there’s a background Color set?

Comment: Then use `Shift`+`Command`+`K` to clean your Xcode project. Or delete a build and rebuild app again. As you can see my `.hdr` BG is ok.

Comment: note that it is better to use a file path or URL to avoid having the image data several times in memory (once for for `UImage`, once for SceneKit's internal handling of Metal texture contents)

Comment: Totally agree..

Comment: @AndyJazz Did a clean build. Even rebooted everything... still no success with the background. Really weird.
@mnuages so you'd recommend to put: `sceneView.scene?.lightingEnvironment.contents = "std.hdr"` to avoid using memory for having the UIImage instance?

Comment: Mario, try my project – https://dropmefiles.com/mBNwI – (password `123`)

Comment: Thanks that works. Actually I did my own ViewClass by inheriting from `SCNView` so i had a `init(coder: NSCoder)` constructor and set `frame = .zero` inside that initializer. Might that be the issue?

Comment: potentially yes

Comment: I tried a little bit longer with different approaches, no success. That feels a little bit weird to me. Why should this function not work when I initialize my SCNView differently? I mean it's still a SCNView object, should its behaviour not be consistent? I've also had no success altering `scene?.lightingEnvironment.intensity` even cranking it up to `1000` did'n change anything. I also tried using SCNView by adding it with storyboard and then setting the default scene of that.

Comment: A behavior must be consistent. Could you share your code?

Comment: https://dropmefiles.com/mBbFY at least vignette is working in this minimal example now (thanks to your other reply). But I noticed that even the reflections in the sphere don't match the loaded environment - it looks much more like the default lightEnv.

Comment: I'm so sorry. Here we go again: https://dropmefiles.com/cfkO6 Pw: 123

Comment: Thank you very much! Now everything works fine!